# Create setup file from C# project with SQL server database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I want to create a setup file from a C# project in Visual Studio 2015 that attaches a SQL server database, and I want to run that setup file on another system and run without Visual Studio and SQL server

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL database" ?? SQL is a **query language** - not a database product - you cannot "install" SQL ...... please add a relevant tag for an actual **database product** (like MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 or whatever you might be using) to your question

Comment: sql server database

Comment: every body going for down vote no one tell the answer of my question and what is the reason on down vote, give some comments and then down vote

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to create a stand-alone application with a local sqlce database?

Comment: want to create setup file of c# project with sql server database

Comment: This question can't be answered as it is. A quick google search will show you a ton of options for creating an installer, but picking one and figuring out how to write it requires a lot more details. SO is more for answering specific questions; this sounds more like a request for a walkthrough or for someone to write it for you.

Comment: Please, show what you have done so far, what problem have you encountered and then that problem can be adressed. The question is too generic. You haven't even specified what type of project you are trying to deploy(web,desktop or some service), but it makes some difference. That's why you are downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You are have two solutions

1. You should develop your application with SQL express on .NET framework or after develop with SQL Server change connection string from SQL Server to SQL express and rebuild it, be sure you create initialize DbContext class to set some data for run your application at first time with base and default data. [Such as application users and rolls and groups].
2. You should develop your application with dependency injection pattern [Microsoft Unity, IoC] then modify or replace one interface to change your developed application database.

Then Right click on project in solution explorer and publish it and give to customer.

Answer (score 0):

The customer server has to run some kind of SQL Server if you want the SQL data to be accessed somehow. One thing you can do is to deploy your C# project with Visual Studio, export all needed tables (including their data if you want that) from whatever server you are using (for example MySQL) into a .sql file and pack everything, including instructions on how to install the sql server and your application, into a zip file and ship it to your customer.
What I do with my website application is, that I include a .bat that fetches everything from my git repository, deploys my web application on an existing IIS-Server on the current computer (with 'aspnet_compiler -f -c -u -errorstack -v /web -p "source directory" -d "target directory"' and 'iisreset /noforce') and automatically imports the SQL tables to an existing MySQL Server (with mysql --host=localhost --user=user --password=password --database=database < Backup.sql).
Sorry for that general answer, but you're question really wasn't that precise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a setup of your project then,

Click on Build on the top of visual studio tab and then click on Publish "yourprojectname" click on it and your setup file will be ready.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

### **Use LocalDB,**

(no need to at least open sql server management studio)

When you create Setup file add prerequisite

1. .net framework `version`
2. sql server (2012 -2019) express localdb

**Add connection string correctly!**

Answer (score -1):

So from what I can gather you are looking for an easy way to distribute your database schema to clients, is that correct? If so then I don't see how you could intend to run the setup without SQL Server (without VS is fine though).

Assuming my assumption is the case then I think you need to think about a solution that will handle schema upgrades as your project develops, in which case it's essential that you move to Database Projects in Visual Studio as it will handle upgrading the schema automatically, and allow you to run change scripts for the things it can't do automatically (like when you've changed a column type or removed a column etc).

Here are some links to get you started:

- [Working with Database Projects (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Introducting Database Projects for Visual Studio (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWKllVyozOg)

Using the knowledge that CSPROJ files are just MSBUILD scripts at the end of the day you can now publish the database project during whatever your installation/upgrade system is using `msbuild` which is included in the .NET framework i.e. you don't need Visual Studio.

This is by far the most robust and reliable way of dealing with database deployment. I would advise staying well clear of automated tools like Redgate, they do a great job for small projects that maybe get used in an office etc but for professional software development you need more guarantees and control.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [this](https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/yd1wtzmhfo?popover=true), with Octopus deploy.

Or, you can try with [Code First migration](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Have you already existing database, or development starts now?

Comment: database exist and connected with visual studio